# URLSession does not call API. Though in Playground it works

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, urlsession

So this code works for me in playground but for some reason `URLSession.shared.dataTask(...` doesnt call my flask api that im currently locally running. Any idea on what's wrong? So far I'm only concerned on why it does not enter the `do{`in my project but it works properly in playground.

```
    func getWords() -> [Word]{
    var words = [Word]()
    let url = URL(string: self.url)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    
    print("XD")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                print("A")
                if let data = data{
                    print("B")
                    if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Word].self, from: data){
                        group.enter()
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(){
                            words = decodedResponse
                            print("C")
                            print(words)
                            group.leave()
                        }
                    }
                }
                print("DD")
            } catch {
                print("Words.swift Error in try catch")
            }
    group.enter()
    }).resume()
    group.leave()

    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
           print(words)
         })
    print("ASDASD WORDS: \(words)")
    
    for _ in 1 ... 4 {
        // - to make sure there aren't duplicates -
        
        var wordId:Int = Int.random(in: 0..<words.count)
        while randomIds.contains(wordId){
            wordId = Int.random(in: 0..<words.count)
        }
        randomIds.append(wordId)
    }
    //returns 4 words
    return words
}
```

Comment: Don't use `group.wait`.  Use `group.enter` before you call `resume` and use `group.notify { }` to execute code after the dispatch group is empty

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for ur response paul. Okay, I edited the code but I mean that wouldn't solve the issue of my API being called right? cuz it didn't.

Comment: What output do you get?  Are you running on the simulator or a real device?

Comment: @Paulw11 I am using the simulator in xcode. My only output is "XD". And using breakpoints I know it doesnt enter the 'do{'. Meaning that 'URLSession.shared.dataTask(' is messing up.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show your current code, because the way you have the dispatch group code in the current question code is wrong and will cause problems due to thread blocking

Comment: @Paulw11 I have edited the code to my current version.

Comment: I also tried adding `group.enter()` before `URLSession.shared` instead which did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using `DispatchGroup` correctly; You should call `enter` before you start the asynchronous work and `leave` once it is complete.  You can then use `notify` to perform some operation.

However, you don't really need a `DispatchGroup` in this situation; You have that because you are trying to turn an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one;

The correct approach is to accept that the operation is asynchronous and it isn't possible for this function to `return` `[Word]`.  You will need to refactor the function to accept a completion handler closure and invoke that with the result.

Something like this:

```
func getWords(completionHandler:@escaping (Result<[Word], Error>) -> Void)  -> Void{
    var words = [Word]()
    let url = URL(string: self.url)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)  // Note you should use a guard and call the completion handler with an error if url is `nil`
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completionHandler(.failure(error))
        } else {
            do {
                if let data = data {
                   let words = try JSONDecoder().decode([Word].self, from: data)
                   completionHandler(.success(words))
                } else {
                   // TODO call completionHander with a .failure(SomeError)
                }
            } catch {
                completionHandler(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }).resume() 
}
```

Then you can call it:

```
getWords() { result in 
    switch result {
    case .success(let words):
        print(words)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks paul.i've never used anything like `completionHandler:@escaping (Result<[Word], Error>) -> Void` what exactly does it mean to place this in the function parameters? What does @escaping do? So does this technicaly still turn this synchronous since (I'm going to assume) that the completionhandler waits till it is executed properly and on `completionHandler(.success(words))` will return the words.

Comment: You are passing a [closure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) (an anonymous block of code) to the function. The function can execute this closure when it has a result. It isn't synchronous since nothing "waits". If you had `print("hi")` after the call to 'getWords` you will see that hi is printed before the words are printed. `@escaping` indicates that the closure will be called after the function has returned.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for all your help Paul! I have edited my code to the above stuff but unfortunately, I have the same problem... It does not make the URLSession call. So it skips everything between `URLSession call` and `.resume()`

Comment: It doesn't "skip" it. That code executes later, once the network operation is complete. Set a breakpoint in the completion handler closure. If the completion handler doesn't get called then you need to look at the class where this function is contained. Is the reference to that class going out of scope before the network operation completes?

Comment: So this does work. Only problem is that I need the data from the api call right after I am calling `.getWords`. So the program has been breaking on me because I was using it before `the network operation was complete`. But now how can I make this work if I need the data right after .getWords?

Comment: You can't. That is why you pass a closure. You have to use the words n the closure. It takes time for network operations to complete. It is like asking "why can't I eat the cake as soon as I put it in the oven?". See http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223424/discussion-between-raaamonnn-and-paulw11).